# Vertex Paint disappears after switching to edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, vertex-paint

Basically, after painting the vertices, I noticed that at some point while editing my scene, they disappeared ...
and I tested every step i did before to find out what was causing it to disappear.
I found that, for some reason, ***entering edit mode and exiting edit mode deleted my vertex painting***.
So I recorded a video showing exactly how it happens:

https://i.imgur.com/Y3X2w9B.mp4

**My thought about it:** *For some reason the vertex paint goes 100% white, that is the default color when you create a new one. I know it could happen if u decimate or somehow change the amount of vertex of your object, but I'm just entering edit mode and not changing anything... I don't know if its a bug or I am doing something wrong. pls help!*

Comment: This looks like a bug, does your object have active modifiers ?

Comment: And are you using any add-on ?

Comment: @Gorgious No, There's no add-on, and I think the only modifier was a subdivision surface that I removed, at the end I think it was a bug, I did start it all over and it didn't happen again!